# How can I use this function properly?

Tags: javascript

My professor sent one library and we have to use the functions to develop some activities. I'm trying to print one vector and matrix using the functions below but I'm doing wrong.

I'm doing this:

```
<table id="myTable"></table>

printVtable(VetorMedia,myTable);
printMtable(Matriz, myTable);

function printVtable(v,table)
{
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(table).rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = v[i];
    }
}
function printMtable(m,table)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < m.length; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( var k = 0; k < m[i].length; k++ ) 
        {
            document.getElementById(table).rows[i+1].cells[k+1].innerHTML = m[i][k];        
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Hmm there is a many error in your code. 1st) where VetorMedia and Matriz comes from? 2nd) Embed your javascript into <script>...</script> 3rd) myTable needs to be enclose between quotes (" or ') 4th) Your functions are declared at the end but called at the beginning.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil Your 4th "error" is solved through JavaScript's hoisting. https://jsfiddle.net/gre4z9mt/

Comment: @Gavin yeah you're right, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

I ran both matrix on the same table, you should probably use separate tables.  Also, I fixed the height and width to match the arrays, you could design your functions to build the table, as needed.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/9wzs5zpx/

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
var vectorMedia = [0,1,2,3,4];
var matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

printVtable(vectorMedia,"myTable");
printMtable(matrix, "myTable");

function printVtable(v,table)
{
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(table).rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = v[i];
    }
}
function printMtable(m,table)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < m.length; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( var k = 0; k < m[i].length; k++ ) 
        {
            document.getElementById(table).rows[i+1].cells[k+1].innerHTML = m[i][k];        
        }

    }   
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Sorry for my uncomplete question. First question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You might want to wait a bit to mark a correct answer; see if someone gives you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything else I can do.

Answer (score 0):

same answer, just eliminating the need to pre-design the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <table id="myTable" border="1px"></table>
    <script>
      var vectorMedia = [0,1,2,3,4];
      var matrix = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

      function printVtable(v,table)
      {
        var t = document.getElementById(table);
        var row = t.insertRow(0);
        for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++)
        {
          var cell = row.insertCell(0);
          cell.innerHTML = v[i];
        }
      }

      printVtable(vectorMedia, "myTable");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```